# Fortran variable type conversion

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Quick question.
I have a fortran77 subroutine with a variable declaration

```
DIMENSIONS HH(13, 1000)
```

I assume that since no type is specified, this variable is an array of integers. Later in the programme I have a loop in which there is the following line:

```
HH(2,N) = HH(4,N) + W2
```

W2 is not explicitly declared in the subroutine, nor is it passed as an argument. I assume that it is types by default as a real variable.

I guess that for the above command, W2 is converted to an integer before it is added to HH(4,N). Is this correct?

Apologies if this is really basic.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you think that an implicitly typed variable in one part of the code will be `INTEGER`, and another implicitly typed variable in a different part of the code will be `REAL`?

Comment: I read that the default type for a variable in fortran is real, except when the variable name starts with a letter between "I" and "N". And because I'm a moron, I got it into my head that HH fell in that range and was wondering how fortran handled the supposed type conversion so I could replicate it in C#. But you sorted my confusion out :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran 77, variables starting with I, J, K, L, M, or N are implicitly `INTEGER` unless defined otherwise. All other variables are implicitly `REAL`. This implies your array HH is `REAL`. So the result

```
HH(2,N) = HH(4,N) + W2
```

will be `REAL` with no implicit casting involved.

Comment: This STILL applies, even in Fortran 2008!   This is why it is strongly recommended to use "implicit none", so that implicit typing won't apply if you forget to explicitly type a variable.  Or use a compiler option for the same effect, such as -fimplicit-none for gfortran.